# Changing themes in Android

Tags: android, themes

I want to change the theme of a specific activity in android. I have an application theme that is set, but want to set a specific theme for a specific activity. I cannot do it in the onCreate() with the way the application has been developed, and would like to do it in the view.xml file by doing android:theme="DarkTheme". However, this does not work, does anyone know a work around?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply specify it for the activity you want in your manifest file.
So for example

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/THE_THEME_YOU_WANT">
</activity>
```

Comment: It is not an activity. Simply a View.java file, that extends FrameLayout. I return that object and I do a addView(view).

Answer (score 1):

Try change theme of activity you want in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_your_activity"
    android:theme="@style/YourTheme">
</activity>
```